# Load list into Datagrid View C#

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Forms Application I am working on and am using the language C#. I have a Txt file called "UnorderedIDValues.Txt" that I am importing into a DataGrid View. Here is the code I have so far:

```
private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (File.Exists(DATA_FILE_NAME))
    fileIn = File.OpenText(DATA_FILE_NAME);
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show(DATA_FILE_NAME + " does not exist", "Abort Execution",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    Application.Exit();
  }

  if (listCountTextBox.ReadInt(out index))
    for (index = 1; index <= 1240000; index++)
      idList.Add(index);
  fileIn.Close();
  DisplayIDList(displayDGV);


}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is: I have a button to load the list into the DataGrid View, which loads just fine, but it's the whole list which isn't what I want. I have an ETextbox that I am wanting to be able to put in a number and only generate that number of values. I feel like I am pretty close, but I just can't wrap my head around writing the correct logic. There are 1,240,000 Values in that text file that are formatted like this: "000-0000"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: so you are trying to load `n` lines defined by the input in the `TexBok`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the purpose of `idList` but actually you are reading `index` value from the `TextBox` and then you are setting it to `1`. And then you cycle till `index <= 124000`

Change your `for` loop to the following:

```
for (i = 1; i <= index; i++)
      idList.Add(i);
```

You can also do it using **Linq** avoiding the `for` loop:

```
idList.addRange(Enumerable.Range(1, index));
```